# How to make links clickable in text?

Tags: html, css, angular, hyperlink, textarea

I develop a web app where users can post text, images, Files
a post text can contain links also, for example

```
this is my webpage link: https://demo.com/page1/home
```

I store the above text in the database and I want to make
`https://demo.com/page1/home`
this text is clickable.
What can I do..?

For example, I want something as follows

Comments use mini-Markdown formatting:

```
[link](http://example.com)
```

I store post text in a variable userPostObj.post_text

```
<mat-card-content>
        <pre class="post-text">{{userPostObj.post_text}}</pre>
    </mat-card-content>
```

as above I use mat-card to display post.

Comment: reproducable example please

Answer (score 1):

Use this [K-Coding's SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220617/angular-12-d3-tree-displaying-a-routerlink/71390852#71390852)

If you want to navigate to an external url, you not use router.navigate else

```
constructor(...,@Inject(DOCUMENT) readonly document: Document) {}

get window(): Window { return this.document.defaultView; }

@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e: any) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    if (href)
    {
      this.window.open(href);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `<a> & </a>` tags - these tags define a hyperlink.

Comment: No ... this is not what i want

Comment: I want functionality like StackOverflow == Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

Before you render the entire text, you have to wrap it with anchor tag `<a>` and add `href` property on it with text as its value.

```
<a href="https://demo.com/page1/home">https://demo.com/page1/home</a>
```

Comment: No this is not what i want..!

Comment: I want functionality like StackOverflow == Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: [link](http://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

You should use  and pass url in href value like this:

```
<a href="https://demo.com/page1/home">https://demo.com/page1/home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use of regex to find and extract links from the text. and then put them inside a tag in your HTML or anywhere you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use this inbuilt functionality in jinja

```
<mat-card-content>
    <pre class="post-text">{{ userPostObj.post_text|urlize }}</pre>
</mat-card-content>
```