# HTML: How to make URLs inside of text clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I cannot hand-code the `<a> ... </a>` since the input is a not known string.

I came up with this:

**HTMLFormattingService:**

```
makeLinksClickable(inp: string): string {
    const regex = /((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/ig
    return inp.replace(regex, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
     {{myObject ? this.myService.makeLinksClickable(myObject.text) : ""}}
</div>
```

The replacing works, but the `<a> ... </a>` is **NOT clickable** with this method! That is because `<a>` not treated as a HTML element but just as text. So the users see the `<a>` and `</a>` and cannot click the link.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Comment: Also see `linkifyjs` https://linkify.js.org/docs/linkify-string.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220617/angular-12-d3-tree-displaying-a-routerlink/71390852#71390852

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple?

```
<div [innerHTML]="myObject ? this.myService.makeLinksClickable(myObject.text) : ''">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the innerHtml of the relevant element:

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=makeLinksClickable(myUrl);