# How to make hashtags in a string clickable and access the value of clicked word in Angular?

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am trying to make the hashtags present inside a string clickable and get their value so that I know which hashtag has been clicked. I have tried to use `innerHTML` for this purpose by passing it a custom component but it's not working.

In my parent component, I replace hashtags with the markup for my child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  tweet = 'This is a test tweet with a couple of #Hashtags in #Angular';
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tweet = this.tweet.replace(
      /#(\S+)/g,
      `<hello hashtag=\"$1\"></hello>`
    );
  }
}
```

And in the child component, `hello`, I display the hashtag and bind `click` method to it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<span *ngIf="hashtag" (click)="clickHashtag()">{{hashtag}}</span>`,
  styles: [],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() hashtag: string;
  clickHashtag() {
    alert(this.hashtag);
  }
}
```

But the child component `hello` is not rendered at all. How could I resolve this?

[StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wp5umh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a better approach that addEventListener to "each" element: this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220617/angular-12-d3-tree-displaying-a-routerlink/71390852#71390852)

but first you need inject in constructor DomSanitizer

```
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.tweet = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.tweet.replace(
      /#(\S+)/g,
      `<hello hashtag=\"$1\">$1</hello>`
    ));
  }
```

you "check" the click in the div

```
<div (click)="click($event.target)" [innerHTML]="tweet"></div>
```

In the click you check about the "tagName"

```
  click(el:any)
  {
    if (el.tagName.toUpperCase()=="HELLO")
      alert(el.getAttribute('hashtag'))
  }
```

You can also add a .css in styles.css to show that it's "clickable"

```
hello{
  color:red;
  cursor:pointer
}
hello:hover{
  text-decoration: underline overline;
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbzcdk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: hello it's **not** a component, you use hello or you can use `<strong>` or any html tag inline