# Is it possible to enable internal routing for the rendered HTML content instead of refreshing the entire page?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an HTML string that originates from the server. Since it's a legacy system, I'm unable to modify its format. However, I need to display this HTML content in the DOM. To achieve this, I'm utilizing the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` function provided by `DomSanitizer`.

The issue lies within this HTML content, as it contains an anchor (`<a>`) link that is intended to navigate to another page within the system. Currently, when I click on this link, it refreshes the entire page instead of performing internal routing.

In the provided example, you can see the HTML string that I'm rendering to the DOM. Additionally, there are two links with the `routeLink` attribute that demonstrate internal routing (without page refresh). When you navigate to the `/foo` route and click on the rendered link (which should navigate to `/bar`), the entire page gets refreshed.

Is there a way to configure the rendering of this HTML content to enable internal routing instead of refreshing the entire page?

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-sttmrm?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { provideRouter, RouterLink, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import 'zone.js';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'foo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
    in foo!
    <div [innerHtml]="html"></div>
  `,
})
export class FooComponent {
  private sanitizer = inject(DomSanitizer);

  html = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    const htmlFromTheServer = `<h2>foo title</h2><a href="/bar">goto bar!</a>`;

    this.html = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(
      htmlFromTheServer
    ) as string;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bar',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `in bar!`,
})
export class BarComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    
    <a routerLink="/foo">/foo</a> <br>
    <a routerLink="/bar">/bar</a> <br>
    <hr>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      { path: 'foo', component: FooComponent },
      { path: 'bar', component: BarComponent },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Use the `linkify` directive of @k-codding that show in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71220617/angular-12-d3-tree-displaying-a-routerlink) -remember include the Directive in the "imports". Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ihpwjm?file=src%2Fmain.ts) with the directive of @k-codding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the component where you have `<div [innerHtml]="html"></div>`, add a call to method that will handle the click on links: `(click)='processLink($event)'`, so it'll be: `<div [innerHtml]="html" (click)='processLink($event)'></div>`.

Then define the method as:

```
processLink(e) {
   const element: HTMLElement = e.target;
   if (element.nodeName === 'A') {
      e.preventDefault();
      const link = element.getAttribute('href');
      this.router.navigate([link]);
   }
}
```

So, basicly, you are taking the clicked html element from the DOM, finding the `a` tag (or `A` node), preventing the default behaviour of the click handler and instead take the `href` value to treat it as router navigate link.

Of course, import the Router: `import { Router } from '@angular/router'` and have it in constructor: `public readonly router: Router`